# Question about AJAX Update Panel

Tags: ajax, html, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Here is the problem im having. I have 5 buttons on my form that appear next to each other (horizontal). 3 out of the 5 buttons had to be put in an update panel b/c these buttons have to do AsyncPostBack, the other 2 buttons need to be outside to do a postback. Everything works the way I would like accept that all the buttons dont appear on the same line. Is there anything I can do put get these 5 buttons to appear on the same line, given the different functionality of these buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UpdatePanel renders a `<div>` you need to style this `div` so that that it displays `inline`  Notice the `Style="display:inline"` in the following code.  There's other ways to accomplish this depending on your layout but this is the most straightforward.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" Style="display:inline">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="labelText" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button3" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button4" />
<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have your buttons *inside* the UpdatePanel to make this work. You would simply need to define them as AsyncPostBackTriggers. You don't have to worry about breaking your layout then.

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button3" />
</div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="labelText" runat="server" Text="Label" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button3" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```